# como mostrar en mi vista regitrar el maestro detalle de sistema de facturacion en asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net, mvc, asp.net-core

Buenas quisiera pedir  su ayuda para resolver mi problema , tengo mis modelos de factura y factura detalle en asp.net core dejo el codigo de la vista registrar y el cotrolador con los modelos

lo que busco es mostrar en mi vista regitrar el detalle cada que agrego un producto a mi factura.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo ver el siguiente enlace, y hacer tu variación correspondiente.

[Agrega cursos a la página de edición](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-courses-to-edit-page)

La otra es hacer algo como esto:
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7UYrkTS020)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/302077)

Comment: En complemento al comentario anterior, te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, respecto a detalles adicionales, solo puedo decir que en el metodo UpdateInstructorCourses y PopulateAssignedCourseData, puede encontrar lo que busca, y que revise el viewmodel que se usa en el ejemplo y como es declarada una llave compuesta en la tabla debil dentro del contexto de datos.